# Forth: Portable indefinite loop with multiple exit points

Tags: loops, forth

I need to implement an idefinite loop with multiple exit points.
Unfortunately the most obvious solution - REPEAT - UNTIL with multiple WHILE doesn't work neither in Gforth nor in swapforth *(Of course the loop in the example below may be implemented with DO - LOOP. However, that code is just a demonstration. The real problem is related to hardware control in an embedded system, so the loop indeed must be indefinite)*:

```
: test1 ( step -- step count )
    0
    begin
      over +
      dup .
      dup 20 < while
      dup 13 = while
    repeat
;

3 test1
```

In "Thinking Forth" there is Moore's statement quoted:

> Many times conditionals are used to get out of loops. That particular
>   use can be avoided by having loops with multiple exit points. This is
>   a live topic, because of the multiple WHILE construct which is in
>   poly- Forth but hasn’t percolated up to Forth ’83. It’s a simple way
>   of defining multiple WHILEs in the same REPEAT. Also Dean Sanderson
>   [of Forth, Inc.] has invented a new construct that introduces two exit
>   points to a DO LOOP. Given that construction you’ll have fewer tests.

Unfortunately I failed to find the Dean's solution.
Is there any portable way to implement multiple exit points in the indefinite loop in Forth?

Comment: BTW,  multiple `WHILE` works in any ANS Forth — it just need to be resolved with additional `THEN`, [an example](https://forth-standard.org/standard/core/WHILE) is provided even in the standard.

Comment: Thank for your comment, Indeed there is such option. I have tested it with more then two WHILE and it works. However it seems, that it is more difficult to assign actions for different reasond to leave the loop. I have created the answer showing this solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some experiments, I have created a solution based on a DO +LOOP.
I don't know if it is the same as the one proposed by Dean Sanderson.

I have successfully tested it in Gforth and in swapforth.
It seems that it is possible to create the arbitrary number of exit points.
The indefinite loop is created via: 0 1 DO loop content here 0 +LOOP.
The exit points are created by LEAVE placed in IF THEN.

Example code:

```
: test1 ( start step -- count step )
    swap
    1 0 do
      over +
      dup .
      dup 20 > if 
        ." >20 "
        leave
      then
      dup 13 = if
        ." =13 "
        leave
      then
      dup 17 = if
        ." =17 "
        leave
      then
    0 +loop
;
```

Test results:

```
> 1 3 test1
 4 7 10 13 =13  ok
> 2 3 test1
 5 8 11 14 17 =17  ok
> 0 3 test1
 3 6 9 12 15 18 21 >20  ok
```

Comment: "Found a solution" could mean "I found a solution written by somebody else and have copied it here", or "I created a solution".  Please clarify.

Comment: Well, I have found that solution by experimenting with different possible syntaxes of indefinite loops. So, in fact, I have "created" or "invented" it. However, I'm not sure that nobody has invented it before. Particularly I suspect, that the Sanderson's solution mentioned by Chuck Moore may be similar or even the same. Unfortunately, I can't find it.

Comment: Single *gforth* exit point, mulitple tests:  `: test2 ( start step -- count step )   cr swap begin dup 20 < over 13 <> * over 17 <> * while over + dup . repeat swap ;`  Not as versatile as several exit points, as it can't return the specific exit test.

Comment: Yes, I know that multiple tests can be combined together in a single WHILE. However, my code was just a demonstrator. The real application (too complex to post it here) performs a loop with hardware related activities, and after each sequence of actions a test if the loop should be finished must be performed. There are a few different sequences performed consecutively in the loop.

Answer (score 3):

`EXIT` of course provides multiple exits to a definition.  You can make the body of the loop one and the same with a definition either by having a separate word or, more neatly, by using quotations:

```
: test ( start step -- count step )
  swap [: begin
    over + dup .
    dup 20 > if ." >20" exit then
    dup 13 = if ." =13" exit then
    dup 17 = if ." =17" exit then
  again ;] execute
  ( EXITs from loop continue here ) ;
```

Answer (score 2):

Basing on the comment given by ruvim, I have tested a solution based on multiple WHILE resolved with additional THEN:

```
: test1 ( step start -- step count )
    cr
    begin
      over +
      dup . cr
      dup 30 < while
      dup 13 <> while
      dup 17 <> while
    repeat
        ." before 1st else" cr
    else
        ." after 1st else" cr
    then
        ." before 2nd else" cr
    else 
        ." after 2nd else" cr
    then
;
```

Indeed it works. The tests below show what sections of code are executed for different reasons to leave the loop.

Loop exited after the 1st while:

```
5 1 test1 
6 
11 
16 
21 
26 
31 
after 2nd else
 ok
```

Loop exited after the 2nd while:

```
5 3 test1 
8 
13 
after 1st else
before 2nd else
 ok
```

Loop exited after the 3rd while:

```
5 2 test1 
7 
12 
17 
before 1st else
before 2nd else
 ok
```

So if somebody wants to assign the action to each WHILE, it should be done as follows:

```
: test1 ( step start -- step count )
    cr
    begin
      over +
      dup . cr
      dup 30 < while
      dup 13 <> while
      dup 17 <> while
    repeat
    ." exited after the 3rd while" cr
    else
    ." exited after the 2nd while" cr
    then
    else
    ." exited after the 1st while" cr
    then
;
```

The interesting thing would be how the above scales for even more WHILE.
The syntax that works for 4 WHILEs is shown below:

```
: test1 ( step start -- step count )
    cr
    begin
      over +
      dup . cr
      dup 30 < while
      dup 13 <> while
      dup 17 <> while
      dup 19 <> while
    repeat
    ." exited after the 4th while" cr
    else
    ." exited after the 3nd while" cr
    then
    else
    ." exited after the 2nd while" cr
    then
    else
    ." exited after the 1st while" cr
    then
;
```

The above code was tested both in Gforth and in swapforth.
The interesting question is the return stack occupancy in different possible solutions. (E.g. in the J1B CPU the return stack depth is only 32 levels).